# Active Navigation Item on Scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I try to convert a Static HTML Page to a Gatsby/React Page.
The page is a One Page Website and each section I put in its own component.

The components are all wrapped by the Layout Component (which contains the Navigationbar).

I now try to find a smart way to identify which Component is currently in the viewport and pass that value to the Layout->navbar to set the correct item active (like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/).

I did setup a scrollhandler in the componentDidMount but now a bit lost on how to retrieve the currently visible Item.

```
export default class extends Component {
  ...

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollMain.bind(this));
  }
  handleScrollMain(event) {
    debugger
    console.log('scroll')
  }

  render() {
    var { data, pageContext } = this.props;
    return (
      <Layout locales={pageContext.locales} navLinks={navLinks} homeLinkOnly={pageContext.homeLinkOnly} prefix={pageContext.prefix} locale={pageContext.locale}>
        <div>
          <SEO title="Home" keywords={[`automobile`, `car`, ``, `...`]} />
          <Jumbotron title={indexData.jumbotron_heading.text} subtitle={indexData.jumbotron_subheading.text} image={indexData.jumbotron_image.url} buttonText={indexData.jumbotron_button.text} />
          <Winwin boxes={indexData.winwingroup} winwinTitle={indexData.winwin_heading.text} />
          <Solutions boxes={indexData.solutionsboxes} title={indexData.solutions_heading.text} />
          <Services boxes={indexData.servicesboxes} title={indexData.services_heading.text} />
          <About title={indexData.about_title.text} aboutText={indexData.about_text.text} />
          <Contact title={indexData.contact_title.text} image={indexData.contact_image.url} contactFields={indexData.contact_form} submitButton={indexData.submitbutton} privacypolicycheckbox={indexData.privacypolicycheckbox.text} />
        </div>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: hint: you will need to find the last element whose [.getBoundingClientRect().top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) property is negative.. but it's DOM manipulation, not a feature of React, so you will need to use [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) or to find some library to help with the task...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will first redesign some parts and then try the solution.